# arXiv number and mathscinet

Tags: arxiv, mathscinet, journals

I recently submitted a paper to a journal with references included, most of them taken from mathscinet (for math papers) and from spires (for physics papers). Now mathscinet does not contain eprint numbers, whereas spires does. The referee requested me to include the arxiv numbers for all the math papers. I ended up doing this manually, but is there a more systematic way to do this? I raise this issue since arXiv numbers could be more important to readers who download papers online.

Comment: ...but not all math papers are on arXiv! I find that request somewhat odd. (A journal I recently submitted to actively edited *out* the arXiv references, except for those papers which aren't yet in print.)

Comment: Did you download the BibTeX data, and then manually insert the eprint number in the BiBTeX items?

If so, I have unfortunately no suggestion. However, if you did something else (and I can imagine some feasible other ways), this might be more convenient. 

Also, I agree with Willie Wong. 

Comment: I guess that unknown (google) is not unknown (google).

Comment: @Donu Arapura: Being the unknown that commented, I can confirm that your guess is correct. Sorry for any confusion...I should really do something about my 'unknownness.'

Comment: I'm in the habit of putting in arXiv references, but there's no actual reason to do so, since the invention of Google.

Comment: I'd go further and say that if a paper has appeared, then it's often misleading to include a reference to the ArXiv unless you're *sure* that the author has updated the ArXiv to include the published version. Generally, the initial ArXiv version is the one that was originally submitted, and many authors (myself included, I admit) are lazy and don't update the ArXiv with the final revised version that includes all of the changes suggested by the referee. If someone really wants to look at the ArXiv version, they can always do a title/author search; they don't need the URL.

Comment: Having a working ArXiv link the bibliography probably increases the odds that I'll look at the paper by 10-fold.  Just having the number isn't super useful, but a link makes me really happy.

Comment: @ unknown (google): Yes, I inserted the arxiv number to bibtex items.
At least technically there seems to be no alternative.

Comment: I wish everyone would update their arXiv submissions with all corrections! It seems a matter of fairness to countries or Universities who can't afford pricey journal subscriptions (and if journal prices keep rising that might soon include YOUR institutions too).

Comment: True, some authors don't resubmit to the arXiv after they get corrections. There are also differences in the other direction: many of my papers on the arXiv are *more* verbose. If there's a short (or pretty) proof of a lemma, I'll include it on the arXiv even if it isn't original (with citation, of course). Same goes for tables of data, and graphs of functions.

Comment: @JoeSilverman Of course it is nice to the community if you update your arXiv preprints. But I also once had an email exchange with an editor of a [Sherpa blue](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/definitions.php?la=en&fIDnum=|&mode=simple&version=) journal about this. He asked me explicitly to wait a few years with updating, so that the journal had a little chance to sell (and it was not one of those over-priced journals).

Answer (score 8):

[JabRef](http://www.jabref.org/) has support for updating arXiv, MathSciNet and a bunch of other identifiers (as well as revising existing bibliographic metadata with updates from web services).

There are two options.
First, select the entries and then use "Tools > Search document identifiers online > arXiv". This will automatically query the arXiv and puts the identifier in the `eprint` field.

Second, in the entry editor, choose "Update with bibliographic information from the web" (the circled arrow on the left toolbar in the entry editor). This will query the selected database and updates all bibliographic metadata. Usually, I use this feature to see if a preprint in my library is already published but it also works the other way around to discover the arXiv identifier for a published article.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the core developers of JabRef.